# Проблемы с удаленной валидацией Asp.net mvs

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Хочу удаленно проверять email при регистрации.
Есть следующий код

```
@model ToDoLIst.Web.Models.RegisterModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <p><input type="submit" value="Registrate" /></p>
}
```

Соответственно моя модель данных

```
 public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string NikName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Remote("ValidateEmailAddress", "Accaunt")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Пароли не совпадают")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

и сама удаленная валидация

```
public JsonResult ValidateEmailAddress(string Eaddress)
        {
            
            User user = null;
            user = genericRepository.Get().FirstOrDefault(u => u.MailAddress == Eaddress);
            if (user != null)
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
            {
                string errorMess = $"user with {Eaddress} curently exist!";
                return Json(errorMess, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Проблема состоит в следующем:
когда данная функция вызывается для проверки валидности значение
**Eaddress = null**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно результат отображения на странице следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема, почему метод вместо строки snovis@mail.ru получает null

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, имя принимаемого параметра **ValidateEmailAddress** должно совпадать с именем свойства **RegisterModel**
меняем
public JsonResult ValidateEmailAddress(string Eaddress)
на
public JsonResult ValidateEmailAddress(string EmailAddress)
и все работает